# Idiomatic way to sequence actions with effects in Haskell

Tags: haskell, optimization

I have a workflow where I execute a list of shell commands, followed by a single shell command, and then followed by another list of shell commands.  The requirement is that if any of the commands fail, the subsequent ones are never executed.  Additionally, upon failure of any command, I'd like to do certain things based on which group of commands failed.  Specifically, if the list of "pre-actions" fails, the program should push log files accumulated to that point to some location (similarly with the list of "post-actions").  If the single command in the middle fails, though, I'd like to parse its log file, creating a separate log file, and then push all the log files that have been created up until that point.

Now, I have a function

```
import System.Exit (ExitCode (..))

sequenceActions :: String   -- log file prefix
                -> [String] -- list of shell commands
                -> IO ExitCode
```

that executes a list of shell commands in order, writing its stdout/stderr to a log file with the given prefix, and returns failure immediately if any one command fails.  This function is built from a function that runs one command and logs its stdout/stderr:

```
runAction :: FilePath -- log file
          -> String   -- the shell command
          -> IO ExitCode
```

The main program is then

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  exitCode' <- sequenceActions "preactions_" listOfPreactions

  case exitCode' of
    ExitSuccess -> do
      runAction mainLogFile mainShellCommand >>= \exitCode -> case exitCode of
        ExitSuccess -> do
          exitCode'' <- sequenceActions "postactions_" listOfPostactions
          pushLogFiles logDestination
          exitWith exitCode''
        fail        -> parseLogFile mainLogFile -- parse out exception and create a separate log file
                    >> pushLogFiles logDestination
                    >> exitWith fail
    -- unable to run preactions
    fail        -> pushLogFiles logDestination >> exitWith fail
```

What bothers me about this is the nested `do` blocks and `case` statements, and I feel that there must be a more readable and idiomatic way to achieve the same thing.  Experienced Haskellers, is there a more concise and clean way to do this?

Comment: You can usually flatten arrow code with `Maybe` or `Either`, or one of the corresponding transformers (`MaybeT` or `EitherT`).

Comment: FWIW, I think the flagging of this as a duplicate is inappropriate.  It's certainly not "an exact duplicate of an existing question", though the question that it is linked to certainly provides useful feedback for solving this specific question.